# Alert isn't showing the translated Text

Tags: angular, translation, alert, ionic4

I'm still developing an Ionic 4 Angular App. I know, that this is still a bit buggy but I wanted to try it in this Version. 
Currently I am stuck with the Alerts of Ionic. 
I want to translate the whole app in several languages with the ngx Translateservice. 
This works just fine except with the Alerts. 
Maybe I should use popups instead?

I wrote my own Translateservice like the several Tutorials said and it worked relly fine. All the texts translate except those in the alert. they dont even show up (see Screenshot)

```
My Ionic info:
   Ionic CLI                     : 5.2.4 
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.7.4
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0, ios 5.0.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1, (and 7 other plugins)
```

the alert function:

```js
async alertConnetcToXY() {
    let text: any = {};
    this.translateService.get('Warning.Header').subscribe(a => {
      text.header = a;
    });
    this.translateService.get('Warning.Connect').subscribe(b => {
      text.message = b;
    });
    this.translateService.get('dontShowAgain').subscribe(c => {
      text.dontShowAgain = c;
    });
    this.translateService.get('yes').subscribe(d => {
      text.yes = d;
    });
    this.translateService.get('LoginScreen.login').subscribe(e => {
      text.login = e;
    });
    this.translateService.get('LoginScreen.register').subscribe(f => {
      text.register = f;
    });
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: text.header,
      message: text.message,
      inputs: [
        {
        type: 'checkbox',
        name: 'check',
        label: text.dontShowAgain,
        checked: false,
        handler: () => {
          this.storage.set('dontShowAgain', true); }
      }],
      buttons: [{
        text: text.yes,
        handler: () => {
          this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        }
      },
      {
        text: text.login,
        handler: () => {
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        }
      },
        {text: text.register,
          handler: () => {
            this.openRegistry();
          }
        }
          ]
    });
    await alert.present();
  }
```

Calling the alert without a button click like this:

```js
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
          this.alertConnect();
        });
```

my en.json file:

```
{ ...
    "Warning": {
        "Header": "Connect with xy",
        "Connect": "Are you sure that you don't want to connect with xy?",
        ...
    }
...
}
```

Screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-eNY85fCHNX4flbJgBI6_3-Ml013ZcSk/view?usp=sharing 
Screenshot Expectation: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-THUDmtXU1GbD97dt62_sl2BKobKMp_1/view?usp=sharing

I expected that the text showed up all the time and not just random... Is this  a synchronisation topic?

I also tried translating the text like this:

```js
const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: text.header = this.translateService.instant('Warning.loesdauConnectHeader'),
      message: text.message = this.translateService.instant('Warning.loesdauConnect'),
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like an issue with timing and the responses from the HTTP call to the i18n json file.

Try switching your subscriptions to the `instant()` call that NGX Translate provides.

Example:

```
text.header = this.translateService.instant('Warning.Header');
text.message = this.translateService.instant('Warning.Connect');
text.dontShowAgain = this.translateService.instant('dontShowAgain');
text.yes = this.translateService.instant('yes');
text.login = this.translateService.instant('LoginScreen.login');
text.register = this.translateService.instant('LoginScreen.register');
```

Information about using Instant:

> Gets the instant translated value of a key (or an array of keys). /!\ This method is synchronous and the default file loader is asynchronous. You are responsible for knowing when your translations have been loaded and it is safe to use this method. If you are not sure then you should use the get method instead.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer! 
I tried this but now in the alert the actual text isn't showing but the var of the json language file is...
so instead of  "Connection Problem" I can see "Warning.Header" :(

Comment: This means that the key you are using does not match the JSON.
Can you post an example of the json file?

Comment: added it as a new answer. funfact: in the desktop browser it works, but not on the smartphone...

Comment: In the case, is there some sort of cache you can clear on the phone? Since both should be performing the same

Comment: already thought of that. i cleared the cache and reinstalled the apk. on the first use it worked, but on every use after the first one the issue stayed the same :/

Comment: @JamieRees Is the reason your solution does not work that the translation file has not been loaded yet?

Comment: @kvetis that could be possible, but isn't platform.ready()  just waiting for everything to be ready and loaded?

Comment: @SunnyAdventurer It depends on how your ngx translate is configured. Usually it loads the translation file via an external HTTP request. I don't know how that works in Ionic. But in that case I don't think the platform.ready would wait for the response. If you delay the alert to show a few seconds later, would it have the translations visible (using instant)?

Comment: @kvetis with the delay it seems to work, thanks. I will continue testing this :)

Comment: Cool, I added an answer that might help.

Answer (score 0):

The translations are not loaded yet when you open the alert. You need to wait for the translations first. You can do that by passing an array of translation keys to the `.get` method, then processing them. awating ensures it happens before the alert is opened.

```
const text = await this.translateService.get([
  'Warning.Header',
  'Warning.Connect',
  'dontShowAgain',
  'yes',
  'LoginScreen.login',
  'LoginScreen.register'
]).pipe(
  map(([header, message, dontShowAgain, yes, login, register]) =>
    ({ header, message, dontShowAgain, yes, login, register }))
).toPromise();

// now open alert
```